# smartgit failed to finish gitflow release

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm new to git and github and muddling my way through.
I've been working on a develop branch using smartgit.
I then finished this and wanted to create a release which I did and then finish the release to bring everything up to date in develop and master.
HOwever the process was stopped because it couldnt create a file in master saying permission denied.
I'm not sure why but I created the file in master

NOw I want to finish and publish the release but this option no longer available.

I can start another release but that fails as it says there's an unfinished release

Do I simply commit and push the changes in master to finsih this off?

I've still got a release-1 branch in smartgit.

SHould I switch to that and continue with the finish of the release

I'm a bit nervous with git as not sure wha't being overwritten and when I see a lot of changes and warnings panic sets in!

ANy advice please?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Log, having all branches enabled?